# Socket.io room not being emitted to

Tags: react-native, socket.io, expo, nestjs

I'm using a NestJS backend with a React-native (expo) front end and attempting to get these two to connect via the socket.io library.

I'm able to emit events from my server to my mobile app, but for some reason can't get an event associated with a specific room to fire.

My mobile app code:

```
  static socket = socketIOClient(HttpService.socketUrl + '/room', {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    reconnectionDelay: 1000,
    reconnection: true
  });

  //Called on button click
  static joinRoom(roomId) {
    console.log('subscribing to room', roomId); //This successfully logs to the console
    RoomListener.socket.emit('room-subscription', roomId);
    RoomListener.socket.on('room-event', function(data) {
       console.log(data); //This never happens!
    }
  }
```

and my backend code:

```
@WebSocketGateway(80, { namespace: 'room' })
export class RoomGateway implements OnGatewayConnection {
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;

  handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]) {
    //These successfully log to the console
    console.log('connection');
    console.log(client.id);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('room-subscription')
  async joinRoom(
    @MessageBody() data: string,
    @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket,
  ): Promise<string> {
    console.log('adding to room ', data); //This successfully logs to the console
    socket.join(data);
    return data;
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('roomTest')
  roomTest(
    @MessageBody() data: string,
    @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket,
  ): string {
    console.log('emitting to room', roomId); //This successfully logs to the console with the proper data
    this.server.in(roomId).emit('room-event', 'hello');

    return data;
  }
}
```

I've also tried `this.server.of('/room').in(roomId).emit('room-event', 'hello);`
as well as `this.server.to(...).emit(...)` and the same 3 combinations with `this.server.sockets`. I haven't been able to find clear documentation on the difference between those, and am confused as to why I'm unable to emit to my mobile app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('room-event', created);
```

Comment: socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('room-event', 'hello'); have u tried like this ?

Comment: Yes that’s what I tried, I still don’t get any logs on the frontend, could it be due to the namespace?

Comment: I'm beginning to think the problem might be in my frontend. It looks like I can emit an event but even doing RoomListener.on('connect', () => { console.log('hello") } ) isn't working

Comment: check ur socketUrl

Comment: check WebSocket on a different port

Comment: socketUrl is fine because I can emit events. I’m not sure why this is occurring but if I move the initializing of the socket to the static method, everything works fine...